# Regular expression: Escaping dot is not helping

Tags: regex

```
/\b(okay|ok|o\.k\.)\b/g
```

Matches everything but `o.k.`

```
/\b(okay|ok|o\.k\..)\b/g
```

does match o.k. but not if o.k. is at the end of the string. What am I missing?

Comment: What kind of regex's are you using? what language?

Comment: \b I would assume is not compatible with \.

Comment: Please post and example of the subject string and the desired match.

Comment: `\b` is a limit between a character member of `\w` and an other character. `.` is not a member of `\w`

Comment: You don't need the work boundaries `\b`, also,  You **should** specify the language you're using.

Comment: I'm using this in javascript in an asp.net application. Here is a sample string.

I asked him it was okay and he texted me o.k.

In the above string, okay is matching but o.k. is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
/(\b(okay|ok)\b)|(o\.k\.)/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/mA5rV2#pcre

Please note that `\b` assert position at a word boundary.

Answer (score 5):

The `\b` is a word boundary, which doesn't match following `.`, as Signus pointed out.  You want something like this:

```
/\b(okay\b|ok\b|o\.k\.)/g
```

**Explanation and link to debuggex demo:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yLHAqZdPZX_fM8N7)

**Example:**

```
"okay dude ok o.k. yep".match(/\b(okay\b|ok\b|o\.k\.)/g)
// returns ["okay", "ok", "o.k."]
```

Note that the `\b` is still there, inside the parentheses, after `okay` and `ok`. So, it won't match, for example, `okayed`.  Example:

```
"he okayed the idea".match(/\b(okay\b|ok\b|o\.k\.)/g)
// returns null
```

Comment: I need the \b at the end to avoid partial matches. For example, if I omit the \b at the end, in the string "he okayed the idea", the okay part of okayed will be matched which I don't want.

Comment: It's there; I just put it in the parentheses.  It won't matched the string in your comment.

Answer (score 4):

As was correctly observed by others, it's the `\b` at the end that causes your problem. `\b` only matches a *word break* -- that is, a `\w` character at one side and a `\W` (not-a-word character in some GREP dialects) at the other side. Since there already *is* a not-a-word at one side, this will still match your `o.k.` .. but only when immediately followed by a word character.

A solution is to move the `\b` at the end inside the parentheses for the other 'regular' words (the one at the start is okay):

```
/\b(okay\b|ok\b|o\.k\.)/g
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're applying `\b` which is a word boundary, which is why `o.k.` wouldn't match at the beginning or end of the line.

When using the following, `okay`, `ok`, and `o.k.` are matched.

```
(okay|ok|o\.k\.)
```

If you apply the first `\b` word boundary and not the last, you can match all of the words, but this can still allow false matches like 'notok' or 'oknot'.

```
\b(okay|ok|o\.k\.)
```

Comment: this will also match ok in "notok"

Comment: Yes, that is true, which is I why I mentioned that adding the first `\b` word boundary will not match data like 'notok'. With the first word boundary however, you can also match 'oknot'. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a non-capturing match:
`/(?i)(okay|ok|o\.k\.)(?:\b|\s|$)/g`

Using a word boundary is ok. However, it is not sufficient.

Since you're trying to match the word ok in what looks like daily usage, I've expanded it a bit for you to make it case insensitive and still allow you match when it ends with punctuation.

http://regex101.com/r/nR2sO3